# Apple push notification.. refused?

Tags: php, ios, apple-push-notifications

I need to implement apple push notifications with a php server. I think the connection is correctly working but the message is refused by apple server for some reason.

I'm getting this error:

> "error 0errorString
> \n**Fatal error**:  Call to undefined
>   function  socket_close() in
>   **/home/www/76cdd1fbdfc5aca0c9f07f489ecd9188/web/mobileApp/handleRequest.php**
>   on line **420**
> \n"

This is my simple code (with a fake message, just for testing):

```
$payload['aps'] = array('alert' => 'This is the alert text', 'badge' => unread, 'sound' => 'default');
    $payload['server'] = array('serverId' => $serverId, 'name' => $name);
    $payload = json_encode($payload);

    $apnsHost = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com';
    $apnsPort = 2195;
    $apnsCert = 'ck.pem';

    $streamContext = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);

    $apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apnsHost . ':' . $apnsPort, $error, $errorString, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);

    echo "error " . $error;
    echo "errorString" . $errorString;

    $apnsMessage = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;
    fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage);

    socket_close($apns);
    fclose($apns);


    echo "Sent";
```

thanks

Comment: You should be using `stream_socket_shutdown()` instead anyways. socket_close is intended for sockets you've opened via socket_open/socket_accept, which you've not done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually solved. The problem was the content of the message (empty). The socket function works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing your PHP version may not have the Sockets functionality installed or enabled which is why you are getting that error.

Taken from [PHP.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sockets.installation.php):

> The socket functions described here are part of an extension to PHP which must be enabled at compile time by giving the --enable-sockets option to configure.

But for your Code, you don't need to use that `socket_close($apns)` function. Instead you can just remove it and use the close since ([Quote from PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-client.php)):

> On success a stream resource is returned which may be used together with the other file functions (such as fgets(), fgetss(), fwrite(), fclose(), and feof()), FALSE on failure.

So using `fclose($apns);` will close the Stream

Answer (score 1):

There is no function to close socket, you can only create socket and manage it by fwrite/fclose etc:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-client.php

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
socket_close($apns);
```

with

```
fclose($apns);
```

That should solve the error you've reported: not sure if that will actually fix your issue with APNS, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
$apnsHost = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com';
```

Remove "**sandbox**" from this url and it will run.